# Ask for a sample code for HumanLimit structure in Unity3D

Tags: unityscript, unity-game-engine

I need to use `HumanLimit` structure defined in Unity3D's UnityEngine class, but I don't know how to use it. Specifically, what function(s) should I use to have this structure filled with useful information? I would greatly appreciate it if you can share your (working) sample containing usage of the `HumanLimit` structure. Thank a lot!

Comment: Thanks but my question has nothing to do with art/modeling. The information contained in this structure such as bone rotation limits can be set by user interactively in Unity in Muscles&Settings tab of Import Inspector. What I want is to get these settings via script, even if they are from rigging software made by artist/modeler. By analogy, artist/modeler are something like car-maker and I, as a programmer, am a car-driver.

Comment: Thanks but I cannot follow you. Let's not jump to the conclusion that there is no functions to fill it and leave the question open to other Unity experts. Very often it is harder to understand a question than to answer it. Thanks again for your comments.